# Flutter making bad Hero animation

Tags: flutter, dart

I have implemented a Hero animation between 2 screens. The problem is that it's not showing the animation properly. Putting yellow lines under the word as you can see in the picture

[Example of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0ptR.jpg)

```
  child: InkWell(
    onTap: (){
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CityScreen(widget.city)));
    },
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: Hero(
            tag: widget.city.name + 'img',
            child: Container(
              child: Image(
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                image: AssetImage('images/oussama.jpg'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

The other screen there is:

```
  child: Scaffold(
    body: NestedScrollView(
      headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
        return <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            expandedHeight: 300.0,
            floating: false,
            pinned: true,
            flexibleSpace: Center(
              child: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  centerTitle: true,
                  title: Hero(
                    tag: widget.city.name,
                    child: Container(
                      child: Text(widget.city.name,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 30,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  background: Hero(
                    tag: widget.city.name + 'img',
                    child: Container(
                      child: Image(
                        image: AssetImage('images/oussama.jpg'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ];
      },
```

Comment: it is always good to add code, whatever you have. try to wrap it with Material widget.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your root widget in a Scaffold.

Comment: I added on the post